# Why do I get string response from SQL stored procedure using typeorm?

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js, typeorm

When I call this stored procedure in my SQL database using typeorm:

```
const d = await conn.createQueryRunner().query(`....`)`
```

I get JSON prefix key with string result.

For example:

```
  { 'JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B': `[{"id":8405896,"statusCd":3, ...
```

This is how it should be? I need to using JSON.parse, OR I missing somewhere parameter?

Comment: Did you got the solution of this